# Nested Objects: Same Parent Object for multiple Child Objects

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to fetch data from an API which returns JSON Objects in this format:

```
{
  "error": 0
  "message": "Request Successful"
  "data": [ ... ]
}
```

I fetch it with GSON to POJO with these classes:

```
public class SearchResponse {
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Integer error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<SearchResult> data;

    (Getter and Setter here)
}


public class SearchResult {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    ....

    (Getter and Setter here)
}
```

The problem is, that for every request I make I have to make two new Classes, even though the outer Class always contains the same three Variables: `"error"`, `"message"` and `"data"`. Is there any way to use the same Parent for every child without completely removing it? (I still need the `"message"` field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public class SearchResponse<T> { // T is a type variable
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Integer error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<T> data; // We have a list of T

    (Getter and Setter here)
}
```

You would deserialize like:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<SearchResponse<SearchResult>>(){}.getType();
SearchResponse<SearchResult> response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, t);
```

You would still have to make a `TypeToken` for each child type though.